# Why does C++ code create a new exe file when it is run in vscode and why is it so big?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I ran a C++ code on vscode and it creates an exe file. Why is it?

[image]

Why the exe file is so big whereas the main file is small? Is there any way to shorten the size of this file?

[image]

Comment: because C++ is a compiled language, if you have static linking the exe file gets big

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, so the compiler needs to generate a binary from your source code before you can run it.

Comment: @rioV8 what is static linking and what should I do to shorten the exe file?

Comment: The 3M exe size will not change much as you add more code to your project.  It currently contains  the necessary code (from the runtime support library) to implement the input / output streams that talk to the console (`std::cout`) and any code that the steams need etc.  You could try a release build and that might decrease it somewhat.

Comment: `g++` without extra options uses dynamic linking, or on windows it uses static linking, try what happens when you use `printf` or `puts` instead of `cout`

Answer (score 1):

Because you ask for one.

```
g++ Sample.cpp -o Sample
```

And then you run it

```
./Sample
```

This is the ordinary behaviour for creating programs in C++. Doing it this way means that you can send `Sample.exe` to another computer (of the same operating system and processor architecture), and it will run with no other files needed.

There's maybe tens of bytes of your program, and the rest of the size is the C++ runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU cannot understand what's written inside `Sample.cpp`, therefore you need to **compile** it with:

```
g++ Sample.cpp -o Sample.exe
```

Now `Sample.exe` has a lot of information that you, as a human, cannot read or understad, but your computer can! You can ask to **execute** it with:

```
./Sample.exe
```

To reduce `Sample.exe` size you need to optimize it. There are many flags you can add to the `g++` compiler. For example:

```
g++ Sample.cpp -o Sample.exe -Os -s
```

Please note that reducing the final `.exe` size means that the compilation is going to take more time (nothing is free unluckly).

When experimenting with some code ("debug" or "development" mode) it's unusual to reduce the `.exe` size, as you are just focussing on the result.

Reducing the `.exe` size is only done when in "production" mode (when the file is going to get published and shared).

Googling [`g++ reduce exe size`](https://www.google.com/search?q=g%2B%2B%20reduce%20exe%20size) leads to many interesting stackoverflow Q&A and many other sites as well! But, remember, this should be done only when publishing the executable online.

A tool that I use for a final size optimization is [UPX: the Ultimate Packer for eXecutables](https://upx.github.io/).